# Why is my local file not being found by my HTML code?

Tags: python, html, flask

Edit:

I resolved this however cannot add an answer as the question is locked.

When passing image paths to a html file that is called using flask, flask assumes a folder exists called `static` in the dir from where the app is called. In my case this was `test_uploads/app`. So to call my image, I had to place a folder called static in this location, with my image file in it:

```
test_uploads
├── app
│   ├─ templates
│   │  └─ image.html
│   ├─ static
│   │  └─ image.jpg
│   ├─ __init__.py
│   └─ routes.py
├── config.py
└── main.py
```

My call from the html file then took the following structure:

```html
<!-- image.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>View Stock</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="static/{{ image }}">
</body>
```

Et voila, the image renders.

This file location can be manipulated using the `app.config.static_folder`, and `app.config.static_url_path` attributes to suit your own location however.

---

This seems to be a common issue, and I've looked at a few questions on here, but I just can't get it to work.

I have stripped my whole app back to this most basic functionality, and still can't make the web page show my image.

All I get is the error icon and a 404 error in console. The path that is given in the error is the correct path to my image though, so I am even more confused.

Whe

I have the following file structure, and am trying to show image.jpg on a web page:

```
test_uploads
├── app
│   ├─ templates
│   │  └─ image.html
│   ├─ __init__.py
│   └─ routes.py
├── cover_images
│   └─ image.jpg
├── config.py
└── main.py
```

```html
<!-- image.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>View Stock</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ image }}">
</body>
```

```py
# __init__.py
from config import Config
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object(Config)

from app import routes, models
```

```py
# config.py
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config():
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(basedir, 'cover_images')
```

```py
# main.py

from app import app
```

```py
# routes.py
from app import app
from flask import render_template
import os

@app.route('/check')
def image_check():
    image_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'image.jpg')
    print(image_path)
    return render_template('image.html', image = image_path)
```

And the terminal output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2021 10:51:57] "GET /check HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2021 10:51:57] "GET /Users/<me>/Downloads/test_uploads/cover_images/image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `./` before the rest of it.

Comment: as in `image_path = './' + image_path` This does not resolve it

Answer (score -1):

Should be as this
“../image.jpg”

Comment: The actual code does point to the right file name - I'd changed it here to make it a bit clearer, but everything points to the correct place in theory